# Gradle No class roots are found in the JDK path: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

Recently, I have upgraded my openjdk to `15.0.2`. However, after upgrading, my gradle is not able to compile kotlin anymore. When I ran `gradle run`, it produced the following:

```
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
e: No class roots are found in the JDK path: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I have tried to remove the `.gradle` folder and recompile to no avail.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    15.0.2, x86_64: "OpenJDK 15.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_45, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_11, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

JAVA_HOME

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Gradle Version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-04-09 22:27:31 UTC
Revision:     d5661e3f0e07a8caff705f1badf79fb5df8022c4

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.7 x86_64
```

Comment: You'll need to find out where in your setup the `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home` path is defined. Look specifically for the `15.0.1`, that should be narrow enough to not find too many false positives.

Comment: @Andreas, there is no such version on my machine.

Comment: @Andreas, And I did not specify any jdk versions in my gradle

Comment: You said you "upgraded my openjdk to 15.0.2", but you didn't say what you upgraded from. The 2nd line in the shown output has that path, and it must come from somewhere, so as far as my best guess is concerned, you upgraded from 15.0.1 to 15.0.2 and that is a stale path sitting in some configuration file somewhere. You need to find out where that is. Since we don't have your system, we can't do that search for you.

Comment: @Andreas, I think I have found the issue, the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:1.4.32` is the one looking for openjdk 15.0.1, after changing that to `1.5.0-M2`, the issue got resolved. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.4.32"
```

To

```
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.5.0-M2"
```